# jQuery, items not being deleted form cart correctly

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm quite new to jQuery. I am building a shopping cart and trying to delete products from a cart. If I have one item in the basket and then remove it, it will disappear, but if I add another item to the cart, the item I deleted will reappear. If I have a card with more than one object, when I attempt to delete it, it will only change the total.

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var price = parseFloat($('#priceAdd-'+id).val()).toFixed(2);;
    var name = $('#name-'+id).val();
    var total =(parseFloat($('#total').text())+parseFloat(price)).toFixed(2);
    cartSize++;

    $('#product-'+id).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#added-'+id).delay(500).fadeIn('fast');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'resources/addToCart.php',
        data: { itemId: id , name: name, price: price},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("ol").append(html).slideDown("slow");
            $('#noItems').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#total').html(total);
            $('#mainCart').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});

$('ol').on("click",'.del',function(e){
    var id= e.target.id;
    var productId = $('#productId-'+id).text();
    var productPrice = $('#price-'+id).text();
    var total = $('#total').text();
    var newPrice = (parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(productPrice)).toFixed(2);
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    cartSize--;

    alert(id);

    $('#total').html(newPrice);     
    $("#cart-"+id).remove();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resources/del.php",
        data: { id: id },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('#added-'+productId).fadeOut('Fast');
            $('#product-'+productId).delay(600).fadeIn('Fast');

            if(cartSize == 0){
                $('#noItems').fadeIn('Fast');
                $('#mainCart').fadeOut('Fast');     
            }
        }
    });
    return false;   
});
```

Any input would be appreciated

Thank you

edit: is there anyone else who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are calling to "resources/del.php", this is not deleting the item in Server (only visually) and then when you add another with "resources/addToCart.php", this is returning ALL the items (even the one you think you remove)

Comment: i created another page to monitor the session data, and the del.php and addToCart.php worked like expected.

Comment: set up 

Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
        )
)

Adding 3 items to array:

Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => product1
                    [price] => 14.89
                    [qty] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => product2
                    [price] => 17.89
                    [qty] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (RUN OUT OF CHARS)

        )
)

Comment: removed middle item:

Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => product1
                    [price] => 14.89
                    [qty] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => product2
                    [price] => 27.29
                    [qty] => 1
                )

        )

    [shipping] => 3
)

Comment: what is the HTML return from resources/addToCart.php"

Comment: here is addToCart.php output:

 <form method="post" action="index.php?product='.$id.'">
   <label for="newQty">Quality: </label>
   <input type="text" name="newQty" size="2" maxlength="3" value="1" onChange="submit()" /></td>
   </form>
   <span style="display:none;" id="productId-'.$id.'">'.$_REQUEST['itemId'].'</span>
   <a href="#" class="del" id="'.$id.'">X</a>
  </li>';

Comment: in the line 2 of "$('ol').on("click",'.del',function(" say "var productId = $('#productId-'+id).text();", shouldn't be "var productId = $('#product-'+id).text();"

Comment: i have use a span to get data:
<span style="display:none;" id="productId-.$id.'">'.$_REQUEST['itemId'].'</span>

$id is the id of the array  and $_REQUEST['itemId'] is the id of the product in the database.

so this bit:
var productId = $('#productId-'+id).text();
was do get the database id, its probs a bad way of doing it. but it does work when you refresh the page